# Scala: Merge map

Tags: scala, dictionary, merge

How can I merge maps like below:

```
Map1 = Map(1 -> Class1(1), 2 -> Class1(2))
Map2 = Map(2 -> Class2(1), 3 -> Class2(2))
```

After merged.

```
Merged = Map( 1 -> List(Class1(1)), 2 -> List(Class1(2), Class2(1)), 3 -> Class2(2))
```

Can be List, Set or any other collection who has size attribute.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Using the standard lib, you can do it as follows:

```
// convert maps to seq, to keep duplicate keys and concat
val merged = Map(1 -> 2).toSeq ++ Map(1 -> 4).toSeq
// merged: Seq[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((1,2), (1,4))

// group by key
val grouped = merged.groupBy(_._1)
// grouped: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[(Int, Int)]] = Map(1 -> ArrayBuffer((1,2), (1,4)))


// remove key from value set and convert to list
val cleaned = grouped.mapValues(_.map(_._2).toList)
// cleaned: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(2, 4))
```

Comment: Hello, It's been some time since this answer was provided but can you by chance describe what is happening in the last val cleaned statement the _ make it hard to fully understand, and trying to pickup scala and this solution works great just want to grasp it.

Comment: The last line maps over all the value in the map, which have the type `List[(Int,Int)]` and then maps those values to `List[Int]` by only taking the second value of the tuple.

Comment: can it be assumed that the order in the List of `Map(1 -> List(2, 4))` will be as defined above when doing : `val merged = Map(1 -> 2).toSeq ++ Map(1 -> 4).toSeq` ?

Answer (score 26):

This is the simplest implementation i could come up with,

```
val m1 = Map(1 -> "1", 2 -> "2")
val m2 = Map(2 -> "21", 3 -> "3")

def merge[K, V](m1:Map[K, V], m2:Map[K, V]):Map[K, List[V]] = 
  (m1.keySet ++ m2.keySet) map { i => i -> (m1.get(i).toList ::: m2.get(i).toList) } toMap

merge(m1, m2) // Map(1 -> List(1), 2 -> List(2, 21), 3 -> List(3))
```

Comment: Note that it's probably more effecient to not calculate `m2.keySet`, but instead add the keys iterator to the set: `m1.keySet ++ m2.keys`

Answer (score 21):

You could use [scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz):

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

val m1 = Map('a -> 1, 'b -> 2)
val m2 = Map('b -> 3, 'c -> 4)

m1.mapValues{List(_)} |+| m2.mapValues{List(_)}
// Map('b -> List(2, 3), 'c -> List(4), 'a -> List(1))
```

You could use `Set(_)` instead of `List(_)` to get `Set`s as values in `Map`.

See **Semigroup** in [scalaz cheat sheet](http://eed3si9n.com/ja/scalaz-cheat-sheet) (or in [learning scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/Monoid.html)) for details about `|+|` operator.

For `Int` `|+|` works as `+`, for `List` - as `++`, for `Map` it applies `|+|` to values of same keys.

Answer (score 12):

One clean way to do it, with [cats](http://typelevel.org/cats/):

```
import cats.implicits._

Map(1 -> "Hello").combine(Map(2 -> "Goodbye"))
//Map(2 -> Goodbye, 1 -> Hello)
```

It's important to note that both maps have to be of the same type (in this case, `Map[Int, String]`).

Long explanation:

`combine` isn't really a member of Map. By importing cats.implicits you're bringing into scope cats's Map built-in monoid instances, along with some implicit classes which enable the terse syntax.

The above is equivalent to this:

```
Monoid[Map[Int, String]].combine(Map(1 -> "Hello"), Map(2 -> "Goodbye"))
```

Where we're using the [Monoid "summoner" function](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/blob/155f7f534993c30d6e757de990330ac796dad5da/kernel/src/main/scala/cats/kernel/Monoid.scala#L58) to get the Monoid[Map[Int, String]] instance in scope and using its combine function.

Comment: This is not really what's required. This only gets compiled because there is a default instance of Semigroup for String, which is concatenation. So if the keys are the same, then two strings get concatenated. So if there is no Semigroup instance for another of type of value, this won't work.

Comment: https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/semigroup.html#example-usage-merging-maps

Answer (score 12):

Starting `Scala 2.13`, another solution only based on the standard library consists in using [`groupMap`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/collection/Seq.html#groupMap[K,B](key:A=%3EK)(f:A=%3EB):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,CC[B]]) which (as its name suggests) is an equivalent of a `groupBy` followed by `mapValues`:

```
// val m1 = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
// val m2 = Map(2 -> "c", 3 -> "d")
(m1.toSeq ++ m2).groupMap(_._1)(_._2)
// Map[Int,Seq[String]] = Map(2 -> List("b", "c"), 1 -> List("a"), 3 -> List("d"))
```

This:

- Concatenates the two maps as a sequence of tuples (`List((1,"a"), (2,"b"), (2,"c"), (3,"d"))`). For conciseness, `m2` is *implicitly* converted to `Seq` to adapt to the type of `m1.toSeq` - but you could choose to make it explicit by using `m2.toSeq`.
- `group`s elements based on their first tuple part (`_._1`) (group part of **group**Map)
- `map`s grouped values to their second tuple part (`_._2`) (map part of group**Map**)

Answer (score 10):

I wrote a blog post about this , check it out :

http://www.nimrodstech.com/scala-map-merge/

basically using scalaz semi group you can achieve this pretty easily

would look something like :

```
  import scalaz.Scalaz._
  Map1 |+| Map2
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use foldLeft to merge two Maps of the same type

```
def merge[A, B](a: Map[A, B], b: Map[A, B])(mergef: (B, Option[B]) => B): Map[A, B] = {
  val (big, small) = if (a.size > b.size) (a, b) else (b, a)
  small.foldLeft(big) { case (z, (k, v)) => z + (k -> mergef(v, z.get(k))) }
}

def mergeIntSum[A](a: Map[A, Int], b: Map[A, Int]): Map[A, Int] =
  merge(a, b)((v1, v2) => v2.map(_ + v1).getOrElse(v1))
```

Example:

```
val a = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 5, "c" -> 6)
val b = Map("a" -> 4, "z" -> 8)
mergeIntSum(a, b)
res0: Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 5, b -> 5, c -> 6, z -> 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a Scala module called [scala-collection-contrib](https://github.com/scala/scala-collection-contrib), which offers very useful methods like `mergeByKey`.

First, we need to add an additional dependency to `build.sbt`:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-collection-contrib" % "0.1.0"
```

and then it's possible to do merge like this:

```
import scala.collection.decorators._

val map1 = Map(1 -> Class1(1), 2 -> Class1(2))
val map2 = Map(2 -> Class2(1), 3 -> Class2(2))

map1.mergeByKeyWith(map2){
  case (a,b) => a.toList ++ b.toList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution to combine two maps: `Map[A,B]`, the result type: `Map[A,List[B]]` via the Scala Cats (slightly improved version, offered by @David Castillo)

//convert each original map to Map[A,List[B]]. 
//Add an instance of Monoid[List] into the scope to combine lists:

```
import cats.instances.map._ // for Monoid
import cats.syntax.semigroup._ // for |+|
import cats.instances.list._

val map1 = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
  .mapValues(List(_))
val map2 = Map("b" -> 3, "d" -> 4)
  .mapValues(List(_))
map1 |+| map2
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around with original maps you could do something like following

```
val target = map1.clone()
val source = map2.clone()
source.foreach(e => target += e._1 -> e._2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
left.keys map { k => k -> List(left(k),right(k)) } toMap
```

Is concise and will work, assuming your two maps are `left` and `right`. Not sure about efficiency.

But your question is a bit ambiguous, for two reasons. You don't specify

1. The subtyping relationship between the values (i.e. `class1`,`class2`),
2. What happens if the maps have different keys

For the first case, consider the following example:

```
val left = Map("foo" ->1, "bar" ->2)
val right = Map("bar" -> 'a', "foo" -> 'b')
```

Which results in

```
res0: Map[String,List[Int]] = Map(foo -> List(1, 98), bar -> List(2, 97))
```

Notice how the `Char`s have been converted to `Int`s, because of the scala type hierarchy. More generally, if in your example `class1` and `class2` are not related, you would get back a `List[Any]`; this is probably not what you wanted.

You can work around this by dropping the `List` constructor from my answer; this will return `Tuple`s which preserve the type:

```
res0: Map[String,(Int, Char)] = Map(foo -> (1,b), bar -> (2,a))
```

The second problem is what happens when you have maps that don't have the same keys. This will result in a `key not found` exception. Put in another way, are you doing a left, right, or inner join of the two maps? You can disambiguate the type of join by switching to `right.keys` or `right.keySet ++ left.keySet` for right/inner joins respectively. The later will work around the missing key problem, but maybe that's not what you want i.e. maybe you want a left or right join instead. In that case you can consider using the `withDefault` method of `Map` to ensure every key returns a value, e.g. `None`, but this needs a bit more work.

Comment: Just noticed this is essentially the same answer as @tiran, but thought I'd leave it due to the corner cases I explained.

Answer (score 1):

```
m2.foldLeft(m1.mapValues{List[CommonType](_)}) { case (acc, (k, v)) =>
  acc.updated(k, acc.getOrElse(k, List.empty) :+ v)
}
```

As noted by jwvh, List type should be specified explicitly if Class1 is not upper type bound for Class2. CommonType is a type which is upper bound for both Class1 and Class2.

Comment: Explanation please.

Comment: Sorry, I thought it is as straightforward as it gets. But here is the explanation - I use the first map with values converted to single element Lists as an initial value for foldLeft, which iterates over key->value pairs of the second map. And I just update foldLeft accumulator by adding value from the second map to the accumulator, creating empty Lists for keys which are not in the first map.

Comment: acc.getOrElse(k, List.empty) returns a List - it will be a single element list if the first map has the current key or an empty list if it does not. Then I add the value from the second map to that list.

Comment: And acc.updated() will return a new accumulator with new value for the current key, regardless if it was there before or not.

Comment: Problem is I get a `type mismatch` because `Class1` and `Class1` are different types. **If** they extend a common Base then it can be resolved with a modified accumulator: `m1.mapValues{List[Base](_)}`

Comment: Yes, resulting map value type should be able to hold values from both maps. If they are different you may need to provide that type explicitly.
If Class2 is a subclass of Class1 then it will work as is.

Answer (score 1):

This answer does not solve the initial question directly although it solves a common/related scenario which is merging two maps by the common keys.

Based on @Drexin's answer I wrote a generic method to extend the existing Map functionality by providing a `join` method for Maps:

```scala
object implicits {
  type A = Any
  implicit class MapExt[K, B <: A, C <: A](val left: immutable.Map[K, B]) {
    def join(right: immutable.Map[K, C]) : immutable.Map[K, Seq[A]] = {
      val inter = left.keySet.intersect(right.keySet)

      val leftFiltered =  left.filterKeys{inter.contains}
      val rightFiltered = right.filterKeys{inter.contains}

      (leftFiltered.toSeq ++ rightFiltered.toSeq)
        .groupBy(_._1)
        .mapValues(_.map{_._2}.toList)
    }
  }
}
```

*Notes:*

- Join is based on intersection of the keys, which resembles an "inner join" from the SQL world.
- It works with `Scala <= 2.12`, for `Scala 2.13` consider using `groupMap` as @Xavier Guihot suggested.
- Consider replacing `type A` with your own base type.

Usage:

```scala
import implicits._

val m1 = Map("k11" -> "v11", "k12" -> "v12")
val m2 = Map("k11" -> "v21", "k12" -> "v22", "k13" -> "v23")

println (m1 join m2)
// Map(k11 -> List(v11, v21), k12 -> List(v12, v22))
```

Answer (score 0):

this's two map merge

```
  def mergeMap[A, B](map1: Map[A, B], map2: Map[A, B], op: (B, B) => B, default: => B): Map[A, B] = (map1.keySet ++ map2.keySet).map(x => (x, op(map1.getOrElse(x, default), map2.getOrElse(x, default)))).toMap
```

this’s multiple map merge

```
  def mergeMaps[A, B](maps: Seq[Map[A, B]], op: (B, B) => B, default: => B): Map[A, B] = maps.reduce((a, b) => mergeMap(a, b, op, default))
```