# Merge different Map by keys

Tags: list, scala, dictionary, collections

How I can merge in short way two maps by their keys but they could have different keys.
For example I have

```
val query1 = Map(("email", "aa@ya.ru"), ("phone", "ph0997832"))
val query2 = Map(("email", "bb@ya.ru"), ("fax", "fax0997832"))
```

And I want something like that:

```
List("email", "phone", "fax")
List(List("aa@ya.ru", "ph0997832", ""), List("bb@ya.ru", "", "fax0997832"))
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using :

```
scala> val queries = List(query1, query2)
queries: List[Map[String,String]] = List(
                                      Map(email -> aa@ya.ru, phone -> ph0997832),
                                      Map(email -> bb@ya.ru, fax -> fax0997832)
                                    )
```

Getting the keys is easy enough; call `.keys` on every `Map`, flatten the result and remove the duplicates :

```
scala> val keys = queries.flatMap(_.keys).distinct
keys: List[String] = List(email, phone, fax)
```

Getting the second list; fetch the value of all keys for queries, using `.getOrElse(k, "")` to get an empty string instead of a `None` :

```
scala> queries.map(q => keys.map(k => q.getOrElse(k, "")))
res0: List[List[String]] = List(List(aa@ya.ru, ph0997832, ""),
                                List(bb@ya.ru, "", fax0997832))
```