# Scala two map merge

Tags: scala, hashmap

How can I merge maps like below:

```
val map1 = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
val map2 = Map("a" -> "A", "b" -> "B")
```

After merged.

```
Merged = Map( 1 -> List("a", "A"), 2 -> List("b", "B"))
```

Can be List, Set or any other collection who has size attribute.

Comment: http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html should you try ++ ??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map here is a similar question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what are you searching for exactly, but to achieve that for the provided example you could do:

```js
val map1 = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
val map2 = Map("a" -> "A", "b" -> "B")

map1.mapValues(value => (value, map2(value)))
```

However you should be careful to have every value from a as a key in b (I just assumed this happens from the provided example).

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it is what I was looking for, as for your understanding I am working on Scala/Spark SQL stuff so its bit complex to explain.... but its the sort of mapping we are doing for two different tables and I needed some sort of mapping for the problem statement where I can push my logic. Thanks again Kudos!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Given two maps with `value1` as `key2`**

```
scala> val x = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b")
x: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> val y = Map("a" -> "A", "b" -> "B")
y: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A, b -> B)
```

**Merge as `Map(k1 -> List(v1, v2))`**

```
scala> val z = x.map { case (k1, v1) => (k1, List(v1, y(v1))) }
z: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(a, A), 2 -> List(b, B))
```

You basically need to get value from first map then lookup the second map, and just create a List out of those (v1, v2).

Comment: Thanks this is exactly how I did.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
scala> val map1 = Map(1 -> "a", 2 -> "b") 
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,String] = Map(1 -> a, 2 -> b)

scala> val map2 = Map("a" -> "A", "b" -> "B")
map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,String] = Map(a -> A, b -> B)

scala> map1.zip(map2).map(x=>x._1._1 -> List(x._2._1,x._2._2))
res44: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[String]] = Map(1 -> List(a, A), 2 -> List(b, B))
```

Comment: Nice approach, though I did not actually tried it, will surely try this in future codes. Thanks!