# How to merge Maps in Scala with tuples as key

Tags: scala

I have this initial kind of maps:

```
m: Map[(String, String, String), Double]
```

and I would like to merge them in a way to get a final `Map` with the following type:

mm: Map[(String, String, String), Seq[Double]]

So for example:

```
val m1 = Map (("a","b","c") -> 2.0, ("a","b","d") -> 3.0)
val m2 = Map (("a","b","c") -> 5.0, ("a","b","k") -> 3.0)
// after the merge
Map (("a","b","c") -> Seq(2.0, 5.0), ("a","b","d") -> Seq(3.0), ("a","b","k") -> Seq(3.0))
```

How can I get that with Scala?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Merge map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map) and many others. The tuple as a key makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
(m1.toSeq ++ m2.toSeq)
  .groupBy { case (k, v) => k }
  .mapValues(_.map { case (k, v) => v })
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already imported `scalaz` then you can do:

```scala
m1.mapValues(_.point[List]) |+| m2.mapValues(_.point[List])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Maps to Seq and then group the Seq by the key:

```
(m1.toSeq ++ m2.toSeq).groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.map(_._2))
// res80: scala.collection.immutable.Map[(String, String, String),Seq[Double]] = Map((a,b,k) -> ArrayBuffer(3.0), (a,b,c) -> ArrayBuffer(2.0, 5.0), (a,b,d) -> ArrayBuffer(3.0))
```