# How to add tuples values of inner map in scala

Tags: scala

I have a scenario where i have 2 Maps and need to get sum of values in inner map values

```
val map1 = Map("String" -> Map(LocalDate1 -> (10,10),LocalDate2 -> (20,20),LocalDate3 -> (30,30)))
val map2 = Map("String" -> Map(LocalDate1 -> (10,10),LocalDate2 -> (20,20),LocalDate3 -> (30,30)))
```

final output should be as below

```
Map("String" -> Map(LocalDate1 -> (20,20),LocalDate2 -> (40,40),LocalDate3 -> (60,60)))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Merge map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map)

Comment: Your answer is in that duplicate, I believe. You should be able to modify the accepted answer slightly so it's adding rather than concatenating (like that question asked for), but it's the same process.

Answer (score 0):

The question is indeed very similar to the linked duplicate, but I think it's subtly different enough due to wanting to merge elements instead of adding them all to a list - which is kind of the exactly canonical use of the Semigroup typeclass. With [cats](https://typelevel.org/cats/):

```
import cats.implicits._
map1.combine(map2)
```

Scalaz can do something similar as well, I'm sure.

But that's not very instructive, so here's essentially what's going on behind the scenes - there's a `Semigroup` typeclass and associated implicit class for syntax sugar:

```
trait Semigroup[A] {
  def combine(a1: A, a2: A): A
}

implicit class SemigroupOps[A : Semigroup](a1: A) {
  def combine(a2: A): A = implicitly[Semigroup[A]].combine(a1, a2)
}
```

Surely we know how to add ints:

```
implicit object IntAdder extends Semigroup[Int] {
  def combine(x: Int, y: Int): Int = x + y
}
```

And if you know how to add two `A`s and how to add two `B`s then it's easy to add two `(A, B)`s:

```
implicit def pairSemigroup[A : Semigroup, B : Semigroup]: Semigroup[(A, B)] = new Semigroup[(A, B)] {
  def combine(x: (A, B), y: (A, B)): (A, B) = {
    (implicitly[Semigroup[A]].combine(x._1, y._1), implicitly[Semigroup[B]].combine(x._2, y._2))
  }
}
```

And finally if you know how to add `A`s then you can add two maps that contain `A`s as values by just merging and combining any values that overlap:

```
implicit def mapSemigroup[K, V : Semigroup]: Semigroup[Map[K, V]] = new Semigroup[Map[K, V]] {
  def combine(x: Map[K, V], y: Map[K, V]): Map[K, V] = {
    val keys = x.keySet ++ y.keySet
    keys.map(k => (x.get(k), y.get(k)) match {
      case (Some(v), None) => k -> v
      case (None, Some(v)) => k -> v
      case (Some(v1), Some(v2)) => k -> implicitly[Semigroup[V]].combine(v1, v2)
    }).toMap
  }
}
```

Now in your specific instance you have a `Map[String, Map[LocalDate, (Int, Int)]]`. The scala compiler looks for a `Semigroup` for that type and sees that `mapSemigroup` might work, if it can find a `Semigroup` for `Map[LocalDate, (Int, Int)]`. Again `mapSemigroup` might work for that if it can find a `Semigroup` for `(Int, Int)`. And then `pairSemigroup` might work if it can find a `Semigroup` for `Int` (and `Int` again). Which it has directly, so an implicit `Semigroup` for the top level type is constructed and used.

Answer (score 0):

This function does what you wanted:

```
 def mergeMaps(map1:Map[String,Map[String,(Int,Int)]],map2:Map[String,Map[String,(Int,Int)]]) = {
       def addTups(a:(Int,Int),b:(Int,Int)) = (a._1+b._1,a._2+b._2)
       val res = map1.map(x=>{val m = map2.getOrElse(x._1,Map());
          (x._1,x._2.map(y=>(y._1,addTups(y._2,m.getOrElse(y._1,(0,0))))))})
       val map2Extras = map2.filter(x=>map1.keys.forall(_!=x._1))
       res ++ map2Extras
  }
```

**In Scala REPL:**

```
scala> val map1 = Map("String" -> Map("LocalDate1" -> (10,10),"LocalDate2" -> (20,20),"LocalDate3" -> (30,30)))
map1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDate
1 -> (10,10), LocalDate2 -> (20,20), LocalDate3 -> (30,30)))

scala> val map2 = Map("String" -> Map("LocalDate1" -> (10,10),"LocalDate2" -> (20,20),"LocalDate3" -> (30,30)))
map2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDate
1 -> (10,10), LocalDate2 -> (20,20), LocalDate3 -> (30,30)))

scala> mergeMaps(map1,map2)
res73: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDat
e1 -> (20,20), LocalDate2 -> (40,40), LocalDate3 -> (60,60)))

scala> val mapx2 = Map("String" -> Map("LocalDate1" -> (10,10), "LocalDate2" -> (20,20), "LocalDate3" -> (30,30)), "strExtra
map2" -> Map("ldatemap2" -> (90,90)))
mapx2: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDat
e1 -> (10,10), LocalDate2 -> (20,20), LocalDate3 -> (30,30)), strExtramap2 -> Map(ldatemap2 -> (90,90)))

scala> val mapx1 = Map("String" -> Map("LocalDate1" -> (20,20), "LocalDate2" -> (40,40), "LocalDate3" -> (60,60)), "strExtra
map1" -> Map("ldate" -> (23,21)))
mapx1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDat
e1 -> (20,20), LocalDate2 -> (40,40), LocalDate3 -> (60,60)), strExtramap1 -> Map(ldate -> (23,21)))

scala> mergeMaps(mapx1,mapx2)
res100: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,(Int, Int)]] = Map(String -> Map(LocalDa
te1 -> (30,30), LocalDate2 -> (60,60), LocalDate3 -> (90,90)), strExtramap1 -> Map(ldate -> (23,21)), strExtramap2 -> Map(ld
atemap2 -> (90,90)))
```

Comment: Nice, but it loses data from `map2` if there is no corresponding entry in `map1`, and it throws if it finds data in `map1` without a corresponding entry in `map2`.

Comment: Modified the code a bit so that it will not throw exception..Hope this will account for additional entries in map1.

Comment: as well as  map2.