# Scala Maps, merging of multiple maps by key

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming

I am trying to merge different maps that have the same key (account id), but different values such as average spending, max amount spent and min amount spent.

```
val a = Map(account1 -> 350.2, account2 -> 547.5, account3 -> 754.4)

val b = Map(account1 -> 1250, account2 -> 3221.785, account3 -> 2900)

val c = Map(account1 -> 50, account2 -> 21.5, account3 -> 12.7)
```

I want:

```
val d = Map(account1 -> (350.2, 1250 , 50), account2 -> (547.5, 3221.785 , 21.5), ... , ...  )
```

I'd also like to create a list like:

```
((account1,350.2, 1250 , 50), (account2, 547.5, 3221.785), ... )
```

Any help would be great, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map)

```
// convert maps to seq, to keep duplicate keys and concat
val merged = Map(1 -> 2).toSeq ++ Map(1 -> 4).toSeq
// merged: Seq[(Int, Int)] = ArrayBuffer((1,2), (1,4))

// group by key
val grouped = merged.groupBy(_._1)
// grouped: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Seq[(Int, Int)]] = Map(1 -> ArrayBuffer((1,2), (1,4)))


// remove key from value set and convert to list
val cleaned = grouped.mapValues(_.map(_._2).toList)
// cleaned: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,List[Int]] = Map(1 -> List(2, 4))
```

Comment: In my case the account is type string, how can I merge the two maps in this case ?? Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: did you try this with strings and you had issues?