# Scala Convert Array of Map of Maps to a Map With Lists of Maps

Tags: scala

I have an Array of Map of Maps and would like to merge the like keys and combine their values into a list. Is there an elegant way to do this, preferably without introducing any new libraries or updating scala? Scala version 2.11.12

```
(Map("a" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
Map("a" -> Map(2 -> 2.1)),
Map("b" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
Map("c" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
Map("c" -> Map(2 -> 2.2)))
```

Output:

```
Map(
"a" -> List(Map(1 -> 1.1), Map(2 -> 2.1)),
"b" -> List(Map(1 -> 1.1)),
"c" -> List(Map(1 -> 1.1), Map(2 -> 2.2)))
```

Edit to explain why it's not a duplicate of: [Scala: Merge map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map)
That answer does not dynamically go through a whole list and merge identical keys, it only merges 2 specific maps given. As exemplified by the answer, the real solution to this has to do with an elegant way of iterating through the list and not only merging lists, but first loading the maps into a list and then merging them.

Comment: Why a **List** of **Maps**? Would not make more sense just merge all the inner maps in one map? - Or a List of tuples?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala: Merge map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047080/scala-merge-map)

Comment: Not a duplicate, please take a look at selected answer. This is a single list with n objects, the link you've included is merging 2 maps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try below

```scala
    val map = List(
      Map("a" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
      Map("a" -> Map(2 -> 2.1)),
      Map("b" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
      Map("c" -> Map(1 -> 1.1)),
      Map("c" -> Map(2 -> 2.2))
    )

    val merged = map.fold(Map.empty[String, List[Map[Int, Double]]]) { (a, b) =>
      a ++ b.map { case (k, v) => (k, (v :: a.get(k).toList.flatten).reverse) }
    }

    merged.foreach(println)

   /****** output ******
   (a,List(Map(1 -> 1.1), Map(2 -> 2.1)))
   (b,List(Map(1 -> 1.1)))
   (c,List(Map(1 -> 1.1), Map(2 -> 2.2)))
   *********************/
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write my own function to do this. As a starter, something in the lines of:

```
type acc = Map[String, List[Map[Int, Int]]]

@tailrec
def merge(map: Map[String, Map[Int, Int]], acc): acc = map match {
  case Nil => acc
  case x :: xs =>
   val (key, value) = x
   if (acc.contains(key)) // append the value to the existing List and then call the merge method again
   else // create the new key and call the merge method again 
}
```

Make sure you use the new acc (the accumulator) each time you call the merge method!